# Getting No such entity with cartId = {quoteId} on Guest Checkout issue

Tags: quote, magento2.3.4

I saw several posts about this issue, with getting the following error message: `No such entity with cartId = {quoteId}` but none of them worked for me :( Or I didn't find exactly what is the cause of this issue.

I did my own research as well on this and I found out the following:

- this happens with guests
- it happens 1,2 or 3 times in a day on our production environment
- this is shown once a payment method is  selected
- it makes a post request to
  `{base_url}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/{maskID}/payment-information`
  and returns `404` as a status code
- I believe the error is thrown from: `\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformation`. This is the content of that method

  ```
  public function savePaymentInformation(
      $cartId,
      $email,
      \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
      \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
  ) {
      $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
      /** @var Quote $quote */
      $quote = $this->cartRepository->getActive($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());

      if ($billingAddress) {
          $billingAddress->setEmail($email);
          $quote->removeAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()->getId());
          $quote->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);
          $quote->setDataChanges(true);
      } else {
          $quote->getBillingAddress()->setEmail($email);
      }
      $this->limitShippingCarrier($quote);

      $this->paymentMethodManagement->set($cartId, $paymentMethod);
      return true;
  }
  ```
- More exactly from this line:
  `$quote = $this->cartRepository->getActive($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());` . If I replace manually the `$quoteIdMask->getQuoteId()` with a random number. I am able to reproduce the issue somehow.
- Once this error message is displayed in the checkout a pending order is registered. Please note that I'm getting a **valid** quoteId or cartId. I'm NOT getting a `null` value or `zero(0)`. I believe those issues are different from mine.

Do you have any idea how to approach this ? What are your thoughts ? Have you encounter this issue in the past ?

Thanks in advance for any ideas or possible solutions

Comment: Have you found any solution for it? I am facing the same issue. If you have fixed the issue then can you please post here.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on the github issue reported for 2.3.x:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14086

And they are supposed to fix the issue on the PR below:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/27172

Please let me know if it helps you.